# Flutter FCM Push Notification not recieving on iOS

Tags: swift, flutter, dart

I just follow the flutterfire guide, with android working correctly but not for iOS app..
if i send push notification from firebase console i will receive notification but using Payload it will not receive notification.

```
exports.likeFunction = functions.firestore.document("Likes/{UserLikeId}/userLikes/{meId}").onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
        console.log('No Device');
    }
    //1. get the user that like id
    const meId = context.params.meId;
    //2. get the id the of the person u are liking
    const UserLikeId = context.params.UserLikeId;
    //3. we get all the document of user that like
    const me = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(meId).get();
    //4. we get all the document of the person we are liking 
    const deviceToken = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(UserLikeId).get();
    //5. the user that like name
    const name = me.data()['name'];
    console.log(deviceToken.id);
    //6. push notification to the person we are liking
    let payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'likes',
            body: `${name} Likes You`,

        },
        data: {
            key: 'likes',
            click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",

        },
        android: {
            priority: "high",
            notification: {
                channel_id: "faithmeetslove"
            }
        },
        apns: {
            payload: {
                aps: {
                    contentAvailable: true,
                },
            },
            headers: {
                "apns-push-type": "background",
                "apns-priority": "5", // Must be `5` when `contentAvailable` is set to true.
                "apns-topic": "io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging", // bundle identifier
            },
        },

        token: deviceToken.data()['tokens'],
    };
```

i have try send using that payload is not getting notification in iOS.
in info.plist i set my `<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>`to NO.

here is my AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken //*THIS WAS MISSING*
    super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken) //Not sure if calling super is required, but did anyway
  }
  //  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
  //       let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
  //       firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)
  //   }
     override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Swift.Void) {
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    ///Not sure if calling super is required here
    super.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo, fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)
  }
    // override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    //     let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
    //     if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
    //         print(userInfo)
    //         return
    //     }
    
    //  }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        if Auth.auth().canHandle(url) {
          return true
        }
        return false;
      }
   
 
}
```

Comment: What is the guy that you refer to as 'Payload' and at which line do you read it?

Comment: You mean, the notification element other than the title and the body?

Comment: @ElTomato yes.. the notification element

Comment: Use `userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:)` and/or `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`.  The app will get the message through `notification.request.content.userInfo` if it's sent correctly.

Comment: @ElTomato thanks for the reply but i dont understand. where will i edit this ? is it in appDelegate.

Comment: are you using an emulator? Because it doesn't work there.

Comment: i am not using emulator. i know that it does not work on simulator

Answer (score 0):

Create a key in https://developer.apple.com/account/. Then go to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Keys > add. Give a unique name and download the .p8 file and save it for the next step.

Add the Team ID, key and key ID in firebase project settings -> iOS app configuration.

Team ID can be found in membership section.

For reference please check [firebase key configuration](https://medium.com/@01egme/the-simplest-way-to-configure-firebase-apn-for-ios-4ed5e6e14539)

Comment: i have done this...